# Why crash my android app without any exception on showing an alert dialog?

Tags: java, android

I'm currently developing an android app. In this app should an alert dialog ask for an username and a password. The problem is, that the show-method causes a crash of the app. So I have tried to show a simple alert dialog; but there was the same problem. The wired this is, that the app closes without any exception.
Here is the code of the showLoginWindow:

```
public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    // other code  
    private void showLoginWindow(boolean falseLogin){
     LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
     View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.login, null);
     TextView tv = (TextView) promptView.findViewById(R.id.Message3);
     if(falseLogin) tv.setText("Falscher Benutzername oder falsches Passwort. Bitte wiederholen.");
     AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
     final EditText uName = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.username);
     final EditText password = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.password);
     // setup a dialog window
     alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    login(uName.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
                }
            });
     // create an alert dialog
     AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
     alert.show();
 }
}
```

And here is the code of the simple dialog (also in MainScreen):

```
private void testIt(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
    builder.setTitle("test")
            .setMessage("test dialog")
            .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("no", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .show();
}
```

I hope you can help me and sorry for my bad language.

Comment: Do you have storage available on your device?

Comment: where is your onCreate() method in the MainScreen activity?

Comment: if your app crashs, there is a crash report. You have to disable the filters in your android monitor to see it....

Comment: there is always error log.. please change your android monitor filter from "show only selected application" to "no filter".. then scroll find for errors

Comment: I have tested it on my two mobile phones and on a virtual device. All should have enough storage.

The onCreate-method is at  // other code  and calls testIt() or showLoginWindow(false)

The showLoginWindow()-method had been working some time ago and spontaneous stopped working.